# General strategies to avoid overfitting GAMs with very little noise

Tags: r, overfitting, mgcv

I have been working with GAMs (R package 'mgcv') and SCAMs (R package 'scam'), applied to some simulated data I have generated (rarefaction curves for ecological analysis).

What I am finding is that GAM bases (thin-plate, cubic, P-spline) as well as SCAM bases (monotonically-increasing, concave, monotonically-increasing with concavity)
tend to perform poorly in terms of gam.check() and scam.check(), even for basis dimension (k) close to the number of data observations, when the number of data observations is small. It has been suggested that perhaps the data are being overfitted. This affects confidence interval computation as well. In many cases, I get the same value for both the upper and lower confidence limits.

While I do know that in general, smoothing works best on large datasets, I am wondering if there are some general strategies I can implement to avoid the issues I have been experiencing.

Comment: I assume that you've tried actual cross-validation, besides the pseudo-CV methods employed in smoothness selection in GAMs?

Comment: Both mgcv and scam employ the generalized cross-validation criterion (GCV) to assess smoothness parameter performance. I have not tried actual cross validation, because in some instances, my datasets are too small (e.g. n = 10) to split into training, testing and validation sets.

Comment: n=10 sounds pretty small to be fitting GAMs.  Assuming for a moment that doing so is not crazy, why not just do LOOCV?

Comment: The 'caret' R package can do this for GAMs in mgcv, but not SCAMs in the SCAM package.